# Why is Pandas not Assigning the name to CSV File through to_csv()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

[Please refer to the Screenshot of the Issue HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX7Hd.png)

I have a Pandas Data Frame and I want to export that to a CSV File with a custom formatted name but unfortunately can't add that custom name to the file.
Please refer to the Screenshot and debug.

Thank You

Comment: Don't use `/` in your date (maybe try `_` instead?). Otherwise it confuses that with a directory level.

Comment: @ALollz Thank You, that worked!